# use of condition with CASE on oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have the following statement which is going to run automatically several times a month :

```
select     
      case

      when to_char(sysdate, 'MM') <> '03' or (to_char(sysdate, 'MM')= '03' 
      and count(a.cust_id) >'1000000')  then '0'
      when to_char(sysdate, 'MM')= '03' and count(a.cust_id) <'1000000' then   '1'
      end

from table a
where a.template_id = '99'
and a.start_date >= sysdate-1
```

since the count statement runs for a long time, i would like to add a condition 
that will only allow it to run when the current month is March. when it's not March it should only display '0'

any ideas how to do it ? can ELSE be used here ?

thanks, 
Assaf.

Comment: It sounds like you want an `if` statement and two queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle [uses short-circuit evaluation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm):

> Oracle Database uses short-circuit evaluation. For a simple CASE expression, the database evaluates each comparison_expr value only before comparing it to expr, rather than evaluating all comparison_expr values before comparing any of them with expr. Consequently, Oracle never evaluates a comparison_expr if a previous comparison_expr is equal to expr. For a searched CASE expression, the database evaluates each condition to determine whether it is true, and never evaluates a condition if the previous condition was true.

So if you had three conditions then if the first would match the count would not be done:

```
case
  when to_char(sysdate, 'MM') <> '03' then 0
  when count(a.cust_id) > 1000000) then 0
  else 1
end
```

However it's still going to hit all of the rows from the table that match the filter values, so you won't gain any performance just by doing this.

You could move the count and table access into a subquery and make the whole thing one of the conditions:

```
select     
  case
    when extract(month from sysdate) <> 3 then 0
    when (
      select count(a.cust_id)
      from tablea a
      where a.template_id = 99
      and a.start_date >= sysdate-1) > 1000000 then 0
    else 1
  end
from dual;
```

I've also changed some string literals to numbers to avoid extra implicit conversions - it's possible your IDs are actually strings. You might want to investigate why the count itself is slow anyway; perhaps `start_date` isn't indexed, or it's choosing a different index. Look at the execution plan for that on its own to see if it can be tuned.

Comment: thanks very much, that works perfectly! and you are, right, the start_date isnt indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Check this script :

```
      select     
          case

          when to_char(sysdate, 'MM') <> '03' or (to_char(sysdate, 'MM')= '03' 
          and count(a.cust_id) >'1000000')  then '0'
          when to_char(sysdate, 'MM')= '03' and count(a.cust_id) <'1000000' then   '1'
          else  'Your Text'
          end
       from table a
       where a.template_id = '99'
      and a.start_date >= sysdate-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested case as shown below

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM') <> '03'
    THEN '0'
    WHEN TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM')= '03' THEN
    CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(a.cust_id) <'1000000'
    THEN '1'
    WHEN COUNT(a.cust_id)         >'1000000'
    THEN '0'
    END
  END
FROM table a
WHERE a.template_id = '99'
AND a.start_date   >= sysdate-1
```